# How to make patern in photoshop

Tags: adobe-photoshop, logo, patterns

I folowd the steps on internet but i then i saw that it was for older version
Of photoshop: CS5 or so it didn't really workt fine then searched for the new version but I didn't find a thing to do it on PS CC please help me out

Comment: "Didn't find a thing?" [This](https://helpx.adobe.com/photoshop/using/generate-pattern-using-pattern-maker.html) is from the #1 place to look: Adobe's own online Photoshop Help. (I do agree it's annoying the Pattern Maker is 'a separate download'.)

Comment: Which steps on internet? Please give the link! BTW: Welcome to GD.SE!

Answer (score 2):

Select file ---> new.

It should be small (in terms of height x width). Image you are creating here will duplicate itself to form your pattern in the later stage.

For this example, I’ll be using 8×8 pixel canvas, zoomed them up and create a small pattern like this.

[image]

Draw the pattern

[image]

Pattern at 3200 % zoom view.

Step 2:

Edit --> Define Pattern

Specify the pattern name

[image]

Using Custom Pattern

Create a new canvas to try out the custom pattern. With your new canvas selected, Select Edit -> Fill.

In the Fill dialog box, select Pattern from the dropdown, find the pattern you’ve just created in Custom Pattern and click OK.

[image]

The canvas will now be filled with pattern you have just created.

Thanks

Digiscape Gallery

Answer (score 0):

- create a new transparent psd file with the dimensions you need
- draw your pattern
- when you are finished, go to **Edit -> Define Pattern** and input your pattern's name

Now you are able to choose and work your pattern.

PS: There are a lot of tutorials

Comment: Thanks for the contribution! Let us know if you have any questions and welcome to GraphicDesign!

Answer (score 0):

> Select the portion you want to repeat
>   (for accuracy, use the slice tool and select)
>
> Create **new blank document** with the same resolution(of selected area) and fill it
>
> Go to **Edit** and select **Define Pattern**

That's it!

Comment: Where does the text in your first part come? Manual, link, ...? Welcome to GD.SE!